# Recovery Mode is taking too long to erase my USB stick

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, recovery, flash-memory

I had some problems with my USB stick so I wanted to erase it via Disk Utility but a "Operation failed" message appeared.

So, I am currently erasing it via Recovery Mode.

However, it is taking too long and it's stuck in "Mounting disk" message.

Any solution? What happens if I shut down my computer and just use another USB stick?

Please help ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Which macOS are you using?

Comment: @Bob macOS Sierra. I unplugged it and plugged it in again and tried to erase it via Disk Utility but it says "couldn't open device".

Comment: Were those the exact words?  I'm familiar with a dialog that says "The disk you inserted is not readable by this computer," but not "couldn't open device."  Does it give an error code?  (they usually look something like `-1000`)

Comment: Yes, check my recent question in my profile it contains a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that I've used before.  On the Disk Utility sidebar, if you select the *storage device*, not the partition, you have the option to *completely* erase the disk and rebuild the partition table.  It looks like this:

[image]

Compare this to what you see if you just try to erase and reformat the partition:

[image]
Notice that the "Scheme" option is missing.  If you use this option (which I believe is what you're trying to do), then it's trying to work with the existing partitioning and metadata, which has the potential to cause problems like what you're seeing.